# Reading XML from Pascal

Tags: xml, lazarus, freepascal

I created this XML file but I don't know how to read it in, using Lazarus Pascal:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ship>
 <name>Ship1</name>
 <ship_hull_1 hp="100" cost="0" x="0" y="0" width="650" height="430" img="ship1_hull_bsc.png" />
 <ship_hull_2 hp="1000" cost="600" x="0" y="0" width="650" height="430" img="ship1_hull_adv.png" />
<offsets>
    <floor x="" y="" img=""></floor>
    <cloak x="" y="" img=""></cloak>
</offsets>
<weaponMounts>
    <mount id="" x="" y="" />
    <mount id="" x="" y="" />
    <mount id="" x="" y="" />
</weaponMounts>
 <systems>
  <reactor x="" y="" width="" height="" img="reactor.png">
   <title>Reactor</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type>
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>30</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>200</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>8</startPower>
   <maxPower>20</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </reactor>
  <shields x="" y="" width="" height="" img="shields.png">
   <title>Shields</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type>
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>60</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>400</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>2</startPower>
   <maxPower>8</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </shields>
  <oxygen_generator x="" y="" width="" height="" img="oxygen_generator.png">
   <title>Oxygen Generator</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type>
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>20</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>1</startPower>
   <maxPower>3</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </oxygen_generator>
  <medbay x="" y="" width="" height="" img="medbay.png">
   <title>Medical Station</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type>
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>40</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>1</startPower>
   <maxPower>3</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </medbay>
  <engines x="" y="" width="" height="" img="engines.png">
   <title>Engines</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type> 
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>20</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>100</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>1</startPower>
   <maxPower>8</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </engines>
  <clonebay x="" y="" width="" height="" img="clonebay.png">
   <title>Clone Bay</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type> 
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>50</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>1</startPower>
   <maxPower>3</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </clonebay>
  <cloak x="" y="" width="" height="" img="cloak.png">
   <title>Cloaking</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type> 
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>80</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>1</startPower>
   <maxPower>3</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </cloak>
  <weaponPC x="" y="" width="" height="" img="weapon_pc.png">
   <title>Weapons Computer</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type> 
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>75</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <startPower>4</startPower>
   <maxPower>12</maxPower>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </weaponPC>
 </systems>
 <subsystems>
  <bridge x="" y="" width="" height="" img="bridge.png">
   <title>Bridge</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type> 
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>25</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </bridge>
  <sensors x="" y="" width="" height="" img="sensors.png">
   <title>Sensors</title>
   <desc></desc>
   <type>1</type>
   <tier>1</tier>
   <cost>25</cost>
   <upgrade_cost>0</upgrade_cost>
   <damage>0</damage>
  </sensors>
 </subsystems>
 <augments>
  <augment_1 id=""/>
  <augment_2 id=""/>
  <augment_3 id=""/>
 </augments>
</ship>
```

Is here some way to read XML independently of its content and put it in some variables/array? My code should not have to change if the XML changes.

Comment: Really? [XML Tutorial](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/XML_Tutorial)

Comment: There are oodles of parsers around. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at XML Lazarus tutorial: [available here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/XML_Tutorial)